# Using framer-motion with React; code failed to compile

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion, motion

I am trying to use "framer-motion" in a project but my React code failed to compile; please how can I fix it?

These are the errors I'm getting in the terminal.

> Failed to compile.

> Attempted import error: 'useId' is not exported from 'react' (imported as 'useId').
> ERROR in ./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/PopChild.mjs 33:13-18
> export 'useId' (imported as 'useId') was not found in 'react' (possible exports: Children, Component, Fragment, Profiler, PureComponent, StrictMode, Suspense, __SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED, cloneElement, createContext, createElement, createFactory, createRef, forwardRef, isValidElement, lazy, memo, useCallback, useContext, useDebugValue, useEffect, useImperativeHandle, useLayoutEffect, useMemo, useReducer, useRef, useState, version)
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/PopChild.mjs 50:2-20
> export 'useInsertionEffect' (imported as 'useInsertionEffect') was not found in 'react' (possible exports: Children, Component, Fragment, Profiler, PureComponent, StrictMode, Suspense, __SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED, cloneElement, createContext, createElement, createFactory, createRef, forwardRef, isValidElement, lazy, memo, useCallback, useContext, useDebugValue, useEffect, useImperativeHandle, useLayoutEffect, useMemo, useReducer, useRef, useState, version)
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/PresenceChild.mjs 17:13-18
> export 'useId' (imported as 'useId') was not found in 'react' (possible exports: Children, Component, Fragment, Profiler, PureComponent, StrictMode, Suspense, __SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED, cloneElement, createContext, createElement, createFactory, createRef, forwardRef, isValidElement, lazy, memo, useCallback, useContext, useDebugValue, useEffect, useImperativeHandle, useLayoutEffect, useMemo, useReducer, useRef, useState, version)
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/use-presence.mjs 38:13-18
> export 'useId' (imported as 'useId') was not found in 'react' (possible exports: Children, Component, Fragment, Profiler, PureComponent, StrictMode, Suspense, __SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED, cloneElement, createContext, createElement, createFactory, createRef, forwardRef, isValidElement, lazy, memo, useCallback, useContext, useDebugValue, useEffect, useImperativeHandle, useLayoutEffect, useMemo, useReducer, useRef, useState, version)
>
> webpack compiled with 4 errors

package.json

```
{
  "name": "code",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "framer-motion": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0"
  }
}
```

I don't know where the error is coming from. I have searched and couldn't find a solution that works for me.
I tried importing motion from framer-motion/dist/framer-motion and others but didn't work.

```
import {motion,AnimatePresence,AnimateSharedLayout} from "framer-motion/dist/framer-motion"
```

```
import {motion,AnimatePresence,AnimateSharedLayout} from 'framer-motion/dist/es/index'
```

```
import {motion,AnimatePresence,AnimateSharedLayout} from 'framer-motion/dist/es/index'
```

App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  motion,
  AnimatePresence,
  AnimateSharedLayout,
} from "framer-motion/dist/framer-motion";
// import { motion, AnimatePresence, AnimateSharedLayout } from "framer-motion";
import "./sass/main.scss";

// Components
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Banner from "./components/Banner";
import Loader from "./components/Loader";

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    loading
      ? document.querySelector("body").classList.add("loading")
      : document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("loading");
  }, [loading]);

  return (
    <AnimateSharedLayout type="crossfade">
      <AnimatePresence>
        {loading ? (
          <motion.div key="loader">
            <Loader setLoading={setLoading} />
          </motion.div>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Header />
            <Banner />
            {!loading && (
              <div className="transition-image final">
                <motion.img
                  layoutId="main-image-1"
                  transition={{
                    ease: [0.6, 0.001, -0.05, 0.95],
                    duration: 1.6,
                  }}
                  src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `/images/image-2.jpg`}
                />
              </div>
            )}
          </>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </AnimateSharedLayout>
  );
}

export default Ap /p;
```

Loader.js

```
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion/dist/framer-motion";
// import { motion } from "framer-motion";

import Image from "./Image";

// Variants
const container = {
  show: {
    transition: {
      staggerChildren: 0.35,
    },
  },
};

const item = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    y: 200,
  },
  show: {
    opacity: 1,
    y: 0,
    transition: {
      ease: [0.6, 0.001, -0.05, 0.95],
      duration: 1.6,
    },
  },
  exit: {
    opacity: 0,
    y: -200,
    transition: {
      ease: "easeInOut",
      duration: 0.8,
    },
  },
};

const itemMain = {
  hidden: { opacity: 0, y: 200 },
  show: {
    opacity: 1,
    y: 0,
    transition: {
      ease: [0.6, 0.001, -0.05, 0.95],
      duration: 1.6,
    },
  },
};

const Loader = ({ setLoading }) => {
  return (
    <div className="loader">
      <motion.div
        className="loader-inner"
        variants={container}
        initial="hidden"
        animate="show"
        exit="exit"
        onAnimationComplete={() => setLoading(false)}
      >
        <ImageBlock variants={item} id="image-1" />
        <motion.div className="transition-image" variants={itemMain}>
          <motion.img
            src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `/images/image-2.jpg`}
            alt="random alt"
            layoutId="main-image-1"
          />
        </motion.div>
        <ImageBlock variants={item} id="image-3" />
        <ImageBlock variants={item} id="image-4" />
        <ImageBlock variants={item} id="image-5" />
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
};

export const ImageBlock = ({ id, variants }) => {
  return (
    <motion.div className={`image-block ${id}`} variants={variants}>
      <Image
        src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `/images/${id}.webp`}
        fallback={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `/images/${id}.jpg`}
        alt={id}
      />
    </motion.div>
  );
};
export default Loader;
```

Comment: `useId` was added in React 18ish. Check for a compatible version of motion.

Answer (score 2):

Either upgrade `react` to `18.x` or downgrade `framer-motion` to `6.5.1`